# SQL Assignment on how to Join tables

Tags: sql

Had a question for an assignment that I can't seem to figure out the SQL query for:

- STADIUMS (StadiumName, City, Capacity)
- MATCHES (StadiumName, Date, Time, Country-1, Country-2)
- TEAMS (Country, Trainer, Continent)
- PLAYERS (PlayerName, Country, NumGoals, Position)

Express the following query in SQL:

"List the names of the stadiums in which no European teams will play."

Hint: A team is European if it is from the continent of Europe.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a code mill, and not providing any attempt to solve your quesetion renders it *not useful* and effectively unsuitable, hence the negative score. This will put your question **on hold**. Urgent attention is needed for this post (even after being edited by a high-rep user) - you need to provide your own attempt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select 
  StadiumName
From
  STADIUMS
Left outer join 
  MATCHES on MATCHES.StadiumName = STADIUMS.StadiumName
Left outer join
  TEAMS team1 on team1.Country = MATCHES."country-1" and team1.continent = 'Europe'
Left outer join
  TEAMS team2 on team2.Country = MATCHES."country-2" and team1.continent = 'Europe'
Where 
  Team1.country is null 
And
  Team2.country is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

After joining the statement together with `INNER JOIN / LEFT JOIN / RIGHT JOIN`, you can use the `WHERE NOT` in your SQL statement.

Some examples are at 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where_not_and